# wordpress pass the value to another page/file

Tags: php, wordpress

I was doing  wordpress plugin to be honest im novice for what im doin.

i have this code in main.php

```
<?php
$url = admin_url();    
?>
<a href="<?php echo $url;?>edit.php">
    <img src="<?php echo plugins_url( 'images/edit-file-icon.png', __FILE__ ); ?>" />
</a>
?>
```

then i have `edit.php`
then when i click this link its not goin to my edit.php file then the wordpress just redirect me to the dashboard of the admin panel.

How can i call my edit.php file for the same page of the plugin that im working on.

Comment: i think it is best to use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call it that way, what you will have to do is create a hook. The URL will be a lil different than what you think it is going to be. Have a look a creating plugin in http://codex.wordpress.org that should help.